# SQL: table altering

Tags: mysql, create-table, alter

The below-shown tables are connected through the `xxx` field. How can I drop this relation and update it to `yyy` without re-creating the tables (maybe using `ALTER`)?
So, I want that `yyy` in `table1` would be the Key, while `xxx` becomes just a regular field. In `table2` I should probably update `yyy` to `Primary Key`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id1` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `xxx` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yyy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id1`),
  KEY `xxx` (`xxx`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `xxx` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `yyy` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zzz` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`xxx`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: why don't you drop the key in table one, add a new column, copy values and recreate key?, is that what you want?

Comment: Notice that there is really no relationship between the tables. What you use (`KEY`) is another name for an `INDEX` and what the answer only does is removing it and adding another one. If you want the db to be enforcing integrity through relationships, you have to (change to `InnoDB` and) use `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` DROP KEY `xxx`;
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD KEY `yyy`(`yyy`);
ALTER TABLE `table2` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`yyy`);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87f92/1